# Make child view get focus before the parent view in Android

Tags: android, xml, accessibility

In this scenario, I need to make my child view gets the focus first before the parent view.

**Also, I cannot set the parent view to false as far as "focus" because I want it to be focusable after the child view gets the focus first.**

Is there a way to achieve that using XML?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:descendantFocusability = "afterDescendants"` on parent view, and set `android:focusable="true"` on the view you want to focus on.